# Deploying an application to Windows Mobile Pocket PC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-mobile

Iv been encountering problems with disk space when deploying my app to a pocket pc emulator.

So what Iv done is set up a shared directory on my pc to simulate a SD card, Iv copied the program there manually and then run it from the emulator, with this approach I still need to do the visual studio deployment as well so that so that the .net compact framework gets copied over.

How do I make visual studio deploy to the shared dir? The 'Output file folder' is grayed out and I can only choose from a list of pre-defined locations.

---

Sorry maybe I want not clear, when I said "I can only choose from a list of pre-defined locations", I was referring to the the options in the [..] menu. I need some sort of free text entry. I want something like d:\MyShare.

The best I was thinking is to manually edit the solution xml, but that seems a poor approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Output File Folder" under Properties->Devices is greyed out, but the [...] button just to the right of it isn't.  Adjust it there.

NOTE: To clarify, You click on the [...] button and you get a dialog that allows you to select a folder from the device ("Location of output on device") and enter an additional subfolder ("Subdirectory").  Now it may seem that you're forced to use a specific folder here, but one of the dropdown options is "Root Folder" which is "\".  You can then add your folder, like "Storage Card" as the Subdirectory and get a deployment folder of "\Storage Card".  Intuitive?  No.  But you can construct any output folder you want.

Comment: I have the system in spanish, should I change the "Storage Card" for "Memoria Interna", which is the name that the file explorer shows in my PC?

Answer (score 0):

You should think from the perspective emulator not your hard drive. Your shared folder emulates SD card, emulator and Visual Studio do not know anything about that. Previous answer was correct, use "Output File Folder" and put the path "\Storage Card\". And run your app in Visual Studio - application will be deployed to a emulator 'storage card' which behind the scene is your shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

choose "root folder" and "output file folder"="\Storage Card\YourApp"