# Can you specify the folder VS will use when debugging mobile apps?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Hitting debug will deploy the application to \program files\AppNamespace\AppName.exe and attach to it. However, my app runs on the storage card \SD-MMC Card.

This means I'm debugging and running in different places, so I have a slight maintenance headache.

Therefore the question is, anyone know if you can specify the folder VS will use when debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you debugging from \program files\AppNamespace\AppName.exe then?  Debug from the actual target location.

Project Properties->Devices->Output File Folder

Set that to "Location" = "Root Folder" and "Subdirectory" to "\SD-MMC Card".

Also, when you respond to someone here on SO, don't create an answer to do so, leave a comment in their post.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259032/deploying-an-application-to-windows-mobile-pocket-pc#259120).

Comment: Thanks, that's the one.

I'm using a deployment project to build a cab and an autoupdater to install it. Avoided the deployment tab thinking it was unrelated.

Comment: What if I don't have an SD but an Internal memory? I have an Omnia i900

Comment: You can change it to whatever location you want.