# Deploy to Memory Card When Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compact-framework

I'm trying to run and debug a C# winforms app on a mobile device running Windows CE 5. It's only got a tiny "hard drive" memory but I've stuck a memory card in it with plenty of space. Unfortunately when I hit debug in Visual Studio it deploys the app to "program files" on the main hard drive memory and it doesn't fit.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio deploy the app to the memory card when debugging rather than using the main drive? I can't find any option like this. I'm using VS 2008.

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259032/deploying-an-application-to-windows-mobile-pocket-pc).