# How can I get around the "There is not enough space on the disk" exception when attempting to deploy to a handheld device?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, diskspace, handheld

Today, when I try to deploy my Windows CE project to the handheld device from VS 2008, I get the deployment error:

"*Deployment and/or registration failed with error: 0x8973190e. Error writing file '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\Duckbill\Platypus.exe'. Error 0x80070070: There is not enough space on the disk.  Device Connectivity Component*"

How can I get around this? Do I need to jettison some of the files on the device? If so, which ones are safe to get rid of?

### UPDATE

In replay to ctacke's comment:

Thanks for those tips; I didn't install anything to the handheld (besides the .exe in question). I assume by "Start > Control Panel" you mean  Start > Settings > Control Panel (and not Start > Programs > CtrlPanel). I did find the division of memory widget there.

I changed it to Storage Memory = 42944KB total, Program Memory 42824KB total from around 29000 / 57000.

As to "deploying to some form of mounted media," I don't know what I should choose. Here is what's available from Project > Properties... > Devices > Output File Folder:

[image]

For now, increasing the storage memory works, but I'd still like to know what I should do for step 2 in case I come to that fork in the code, I mean road.

Comment: If the device has a Storage Card or whatever, set the path to it using "Root Folder" and then the path to the storage card.  See the update to #2 in my answer for more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options:

1. Use the System memory control panel applet (Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Memory) to change the memory division to give yourself more storage memory.
2. Don't deploy to the Program files directory, but instead deploy to some form of mounted media (SD card or whatever) by changing the Deployment option in the Project settings (see [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259032/deploying-an-application-to-windows-mobile-pocket-pc))
3. Delete anything on the device that you installed that isn't necessary